# Rmarkdown removes citation hyperlink

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, citations

when using Rmarkdown to build a pdf with citations included, it removes the hyperlinks of the citations by default.

Looking at the latex file produced, I can see \usepackage{hyperref} in the pre-amble, but the citations look as follows:

```
rmd input:    @sharpe
latex output:  sharpe (1999)
```

Thus it produces a **non-dynamic citation** in pdf.

The latex output that I would expect is: \citet{sharpe}, which produces hyperlinked citation in pdf.

Any ideas why it writes out my bibtex inputs like this and how I can make it hyperlinked?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default pandoc will do the rendering of the citations. I see two alternatives.

1. Use `\citet{sharpe}` in the Rmd instead of `@sharpe`. Downside: you can only render the Rmd into pdf.
2. Use the `--natbib` argument. Downside: You need an extra `bibtex` step when rendering into pdf.

**Update**: You can also provide the option `link-citations: true` in your YAML (since `pandoc v1.16`) and keep the pandoc  syntax for citations.

Comment: Hi @Thierry, thanks for the suggestion. However using \citet{sharpe} produces a '?' in the pdf, despite being \citet{sharpe} in the tex file?

Comment: Also, I made the default latex file to use natbib, but it doesn't fix my problem. What do you mean by the extra bibtex step?

Comment: Try to compile the tex file manually: `pdflatex yourfile.tex`, `bibtex yourfile`, `pdflatex yourfile.tex`, `pdflatex yourfile.tex`

Comment: That is not ideal though, but solves my problem thanks. Please let me know if you know of a way to make it happen dynamically.

Comment: btw what did you mean by the extra bibtex step when using natbib?

Comment: See http://pandoc.org/demo/example19/Citation-rendering.html `bibtex` is the step in which the citations are generated in base LaTeX.

Comment: `link-citations: true` did not appear to work. Cold you be more specific about how it's supposed to enter the YAML header?

Comment: @MichaelChirico try something like ```---
output: pdf_document
bibliography: Main_Document.bib
link-citations: true
---```

Comment: `\citet` gives me `! Undefined control sequence.` But no need, with `link-citations: true`.

Answer (score 10):

> Example of YAML for link citations in Rmd using PDF

```
---
title: "Introduction to data mining – Assignment"
author: "Your Name"
date: "Date"
output: 
  pdf_document: default
bibliography: <references>.bib
csl: <your_csl_file>.csl
link-citations: yes
linkcolor: blue
---
```

In text quote.

```
Here is my quote @AuthorYear
```