# R markdown citation tags do not link to actual citation

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing an academic paper using only R markdown(without lateX) in which I want to cite sources and want the tags of the citations to be a hyperlink to the citations listed below.

```
---
title: 'Term Paper'
author: "Sachin Tendulkar"
output: pdf_document
bibliography: references.bib
bibliostyle: apsr
---

Application written in the R programming language [@RCoreTeam] 

# REFERENCES
```

Following are the contents of my .bib file :

```
@Article{RCoreTeam,
Title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
Author = {{R Core Team}},
Year = {2015},

Type  = {Journal Article},
Url   = {http://www.R-project.org}
}
```

My output file generates a pdf but does not give a hyperlink to the first tag that says (R Core Team 2015) such that I could click on this and take me to the #references heading below. Is it possible to also have this citation in a square bracket[]?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rmarkdown removes citation hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233827/rmarkdown-removes-citation-hyperlink)

Comment: its not a duplicate, the other post is using lateX

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33234045/6455166 answers your question: add `link-citations: true` to your YAML header.

Comment: @WeihuangWong : that's not working for me with OP's file, even after updating pandoc to v 1.18 (from https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/1.18 )

Comment: @BenBolker: That's interesting. It worked for me in RStudio and Pandoc 1.17.

Comment: Can I reopen this question?  I have tried using `link-citations: true` using Pandoc v. 2.17.1.1 for `bookdown::pdf_book()` and `bookdown::word_document2()` but fail to get linked citations in either.  I also tried editing the `.tex` file, removing `hidelinks` in the call to `\hypersetup{}`, also to no avail.